# The usage of .htaccess to re-write the url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have written .htaccess to rewrite the following urls :

```
confirmreg.php
```

to

```
http://keralapsctuts.com/confirm-registration.html
```

and

```
 confirmreg.php?code=nsfoh98fkjsdf90
```

to

```
http://keralapsctuts.com/code/62fdd2ac2709877a81ecfd7dde9d2810/confirm-registration.html
```

.htaccess Rule is

```
RewriteRule confirm-registration\.html$ confirmreg.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule code/(.*)/confirm-registration\.html$ confirmreg.php?code=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Echo Get not returning the value of the code

```
echo "Code: ". $_GET['code'];
```

Comment: what does `print_r( $_GET );` show?

Comment: It's show the code in the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Improved code:

```
RewriteRule ^confirm-registration\.html$ confirmreg.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^code/([0-9a-z]+)/confirm-registration\.html$ confirmreg.php?code=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Give the RewriteRule a starting ^

```
RewriteRule ^
```

Optionally, be more specific in the characters you want to except.

```
code/([0-9a-z]+)/
```